# What kind of code-optimizations in Views Razor does, if any?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I met the following code:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart", "ShoppingCart").ToString()))
{
   //...
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>@Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart", "ShoppingCart")</li>
   </ul>   
}
```

that makes @Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart", "ShoppingCart") to be executed twice, I fixed code introducing variable:

```
var shoppingCartHtml = @Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart", "ShoppingCart").ToString()
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shoppingCartHtml))
{  //...
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>@shoppingCartHtml</li>
   </ul>
}
```

but still have some questions about code optimizations:

> 1. Does Razor do any code-optmizations in Views?
> 2. When C# code in views is dynamically compiled and translated to MSIL, the dynamic compilation does same optimizations as C# compiler
>      does building dll?
> 3. Could such things as in example above be optimized, by CLR/JIT compilers?

Comment: Its still executing your method twice. What is the point of this?

Comment: One google search for "asp.net razor optimize" yielded this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/08/16/optimizing-mvc-view-lookup-performance.aspx

Comment: Theoretically, you could have changed items in the cart (from a different tab) between the two calls, so the compiler should not assume that the results are the same.

Comment: I like such questions. It's the type of question nobody normally thinks about.

Comment: If your code (minus the html parts) was in a C# method (eg an action on a controller) what optimisations would think might be applied by the compiler (at whatever stage) ?   The compiler would *never* remove a second call to a method in the way you have "hand optimised" it as your second code snippet does not have the **exact same functionality**.   eg if FlyoutShoppingCart records a metric audit log to record how many times it is called, it will be different between the two.  Compiler optimisations will never affect the final result of the code, only memory/cpu usage.